# Scala, a cross between a foldLeft and a map supporting lazy evaluation

Tags: scala, dictionary, lazy-evaluation, fold

I have a collection which I want to map to a new collection, however each resulting value is dependent on the value before it in some way.I could solve this with a leftFold

```
val result:List[B] = (myList:List[A]).foldLeft(C -> List.empty[B]){ 
  case ((c, list), a) =>
    ..some function returning something like..
    C -> (B :: list)
}
```

The problem here is I need to iterate through the entire list to retrieve the resultant list.  Say I wanted a function that maps TraversableOnce[A] to TraversableOnce[B] and only evaluate members as I call them?
It seems to me to be a fairly conventional problem so Im wondering if there is a common approach to this.  What I currently have is:

```
implicit class TraversableOnceEx[T](val self : TraversableOnce[T]) extends AnyVal {

   def foldyMappyFunction[A, U](a:A)(func:(A,T) => (A,U)):TraversableOnce[U] = {
     var currentA = a
     self.map { t =>
        val result = func(currentA, t)
        currentA = result._1
        result._2
     }
   } 
}
```

As far as functional purity goes, you couldn't run it in parallel, but otherwise it seems sound.

An example would be; 
Return me each element and if it is the first time that element has appeared before.

```
val elements:TraversableOnce[E]
val result = elements.mappyFoldyFunction(Set.empty[E]) {
 (s, e) => (s + e) -> (e -> s.contains(e))
}
result:TraversableOnce[(E,Boolean)]
```

Comment: Could you add an example of calling your `foldyMappingFunction`?

Comment: I have updated with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to make use of the State Monad. Here is your example re-written using scalaz:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def foldyMappy(i: Int) = State[Set[Int], (Int, Boolean)](s => (s + i, (i, s contains(i))))

val r = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 6).traverseS(foldyMappy)(Set.empty[Int])._2

//List((1,false), (2,false), (3,false), (3,true), (6,false))
println(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand your example as your contains check will always result to `false`.

`foldLeft` is different. It will result in a single value by aggregating all elements of the list.
You clearly need `map` (`List` => `List`).

Anyway, answering your question about laziness:
you should use `Stream` instead of `List`. `Stream` doesn't evaluate the tail before actually calling it.

[Stream API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Stream)

Comment: Or its analog that tries to not keep itself in memory after being used: Iterator

Answer (score 0):

It is look like you need [SeqView](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.SeqView). Use `view` or `view(from: Int, until: Int)` methods for create a non-strict view of list.